# Whats difference between output of any function whose return type is int and is used with super() and without super() keyword?

Tags: java, inheritance, return, super, return-type

[This is sample problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM5ZV.png)

[Output of Sample problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9E1b.png)

I am confused on the functioning of super( ) keyword in java .
If I donnot use super keyword then its not giving any "return value of function".
While i am using super kayword then its shows the "return value of function".
Can anybody Explain me about that reason ?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the relevant code.  ---`super.methodName(...)` calss the superclass-implementation of the method.

Comment: Please don't post links to code, just post code.  And a [mre] is preferable.

Comment: Please dont give code as an image in the future. Also the naming convention dosent look pretty good in your code it will be better to follow naming conventions

Comment: Java naming conventions use camelCase rather than snake_case. Classes begin with an upper case letter (ChildClass); methods, variables, and parameters begin with a lower case letter.

Comment: The super keyword is almost always used in constructors.

Answer (score 1):

The super keyword refers to superclass (parent) objects. It is used to call superclass methods, and to access the superclass constructor.
I will explain your output line by line :

First line
Area of circle will be 314.0 comes from the code:
Since you are creating instance of Child_Class and calling its method

```
Child_Class cc= new Child_Class()
cc.area();
```

First line
Area of circle will be 314.0 comes from the code when u are calling the parent class area method

```
super.area();
```

Third line:
10
comes from printing the value returned by super.area() since super.area() returns the radius which is hardcoded as 10. Here u are calling the parent class area method.

```
System.out.println(super.area());
```

Fourth line Area of square will be 100 comes from

```
System.out.println("Area of square will be " + side*side);
```

When u dont use super it simply means that you are not invoking the parent class method.

Answer (score 0):

The super() method i referring to the parent class. In this example, Child_Class is the parent class (or super class) and Shapes is the child class. You can tell because shapes extends Child_Class.

super.area() is referring to the area() method in the parent class, so the one in Child_Class. The is the value that will be returned.